# Issue with adding cordapps to nodes while using network bootstrapper

Tags: corda

I am following documentation in here :https://docs.corda.net/network-bootstrapper.html to bootstrap test network. In the section: "Providing CorDapps to the Network Bootstrapper", we are asked to place cordapp jar along with the conf files.

i run the command below:

java -jar corda-network-bootstrapper-3.2-corda-executable.jar "."

After, I see message Bootstrapping complete!

But, when i go into the node folders, none of them have the cordapp in their directories ? How do i know that cordapp is installed ?

Also, another issue with the command is I cant provide the directory using --dir parameter.

Can you please suggest any work around for these issues ?

Thanks.

**Update**

Below are the screenshots for commands in Mac OSX:

This is my folder structure:

[image]

Error I am getting after I execute the command:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your jar should be present inside your `node's root/cordapps` directory. If it's not, than bootstrapper is unable to identify your cordapp. Try adding `--verbose` and it should print something like "Found the following CorDapps: "

Also when you start the corda nodes, CLI will show all installed cordApps.

For your dir issue, please add the error message here and the type of your operating system. It's working fine here on Linux.

Comment: Exactly. Make sure you read this section: https://docs.corda.net/network-bootstrapper.html#providing-cordapps-to-the-network-bootstrapper.

Comment: @kleash Yes I checked in the cordapps directory under the node folder and I dont see any cordapps installed in that. Also, tried using --verbose option. Both --dir and --verbose give me the same error  "No nodes found". I have updated the screenshots for the same. Do i need follow any specific instructions for Mac OSX ?

Comment: One more thing I have tried is, I cloned Corda code base and tried running Network bootstrapper from there and thats how I got it working. Something is missing with the Jar.

Comment: I have faced similar issue of `no nodes found` in windows in v3.2. Try removing --dir from your command and run from same directory i.e. Copy bootstrapper in your current folder and run `java -jar bootstrap.jar`